# what is appropriate status code for wrong email/username when user tries to reset password?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

a simple use case - unlogged user tries to reset their password. they provide wrong email or username (but the format of the data is correct).
should I return 400, 412 or 404?

Comment: Since it's not an HTTP issue or with the request itself, you should return 200.

Comment: HTTP status codes are quite subjective. If the user is not logged in, I would argue its `401 Unauthenticated`. *Edit:* But if you want a more detailed answer you should add some more information about your use case. Do you mean when an unauthenticated user clicks "Forgot Password" but that E-Mail/Username does not exist? Because in this case I would favor a regular `200 OK` with a message like `**IF** this username/email exists, you will receive a link to reset your password`. This way it preserves privacy, as people cannot gain information about which users have registered for your service.

Comment: Clarification to my previous comment: I would return `401` if a user is trying to access a `change password` endpoint which should only be accessible to authenticated users. But because you asked about *reset* password, I assume you meant a "Forgot Password" functionality on the log in screen.

Comment: 200 seems an interesting option regarding security reasons but if I want to notify the user, I was thinking about some 400-ish status code

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

- 200 for successfull
- 401 for unauthorized

Comment: I started with 401 as well, there is no authorization process here though...